# How to create zip and read all files from HexBinary string in C#?

Tags: c#

I am converting zip to HexBinary string and passing that HexBinary result in one of the `xml` element to `asmx` web service.

```
private static string ConvertZipToHexBinaryString(string filePath)
{
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    //01. Simple
    //string strHex = BitConverter.ToString(data);


    //02. If want without '-' the use this one
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    return hex;
}
```

But on the service end how can I retrieve zip and read all files by extracting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you process ZIP files depends on the Framework version you are using. If you got at least 4.5, you have the [ZipArchive class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) wich can work on any Stream. And creating a MemoryStream from a Byte Array is a [Constructor Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx).

If you are before that, you need 3rd party code. It is a unfortunate truth that .NET is really bad at dealing with .zip files before 4.5. Common approaches include using the free 7zip .NET Library or using Console Redirction to use any File/OS Level tool you have installed on the Computer. Of course at that point how you store those files also starts to mater. There are at least 2 ways in dealing with storing blobs with a DB. And [filestream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) wich kind of combines them both.

Comment: I am using .NET framework 4.5 but don't know how to get that zip back from that byte array and read all files and then save all of them

Comment: Use the cosntructor I linked (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) to make a MemoryStream from the Byte[]. Use the first constructor of ZipArchive to make a isntance using the MemoryStream (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158268.aspx). Work with ZipArchive.

Comment: Thanks that's what I am looking for..!

Comment: Can I get back name of zip file from that ZipArchive?

Comment: Propably nope. If you want the original filename you have to send it along as part of the API call that gives you the bytes. There could be some metadata as part of the zip stream wich might include the original creation filename. But if you want something reliable, send it along from the client.

Comment: Ok, understood..!